# How to Run Selenium Script in multiple test environments by Page Objects Model

Tags: selenium, testng, pom.xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE220.png)I have 3 property files and I want to get properties value on behalf of the environment

Currently, I am using 1 properties file for reading URLs but now I want to fetch URLs on behalf of environments like Dev, UAT, Staging

```
public Base_Pace()  {

    try {


        prop = new Properties();
        String projectRootPath = TC_TestUtil.getProjectDirectory();
        FileInputStream ip = null;
         if(TC_TestUtil.isWindows()) {
             ip = new FileInputStream(projectRootPath + "\\" + "test.properties");
          }else {
             ip = new FileInputStream(projectRootPath + "/" + "test.properties");
          }
        prop.load(ip);
        
        
        

        }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @AlexeyR. this is my requirement, you can follow this reference URL of my requirements ........  https://www.vinsguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-execute-tests-in-multiple-environments/

Comment: please provide the code you tried and any error messages so it can be better analyzed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.